# Loading SVG Files with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg

I added react-svg-loader and tried to import an svg per the documentation, yet I keep running into "Can't find the module.."

```
import * as React from 'react';
import FlickrLoader from './FlickrLoader.svg';

// tslint:disable-next-line:variable-name
const Loader = props => (
   <FlickrLoader className="center" />
);
export default Loader;
```

In the root folder, I have custom.d.ts which as `declare module '*.svg';`

Can anyone think of something that I may be missing as to why TypeScript won't pick up the .svg file in the same directory?

Comment: Did you add the loader to your webpack config?

Comment: @Jayce444 yeah, it's using react-typescript-loader

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems like you're asking Typescript to look for a module called `FlickrLoader` inside of the svg file which it can't do for obvious reasons. I would try asking it to import the whole contents of the file - i.e. `import * as FlickrLoader from './FlickrLoader.svg'`